# PAYPAL api call adaptiveAccountsService createAccount getting “MissingCredentialException”

Tags: java, paypal

I am trying to call createAccount method of adaptiveAccountsService in Paypal API from a java class for creating an account.

## My code is as below.

```
RequestEnvelope env = new RequestEnvelope();
        env.setErrorLanguage("en_US");
        NameType name = new NameType();
        AddressType address = new AddressType();
        String preferredLanguageCode ="en_US";

        CreateAccountRequest createAccountRequest = new CreateAccountRequest();

        createAccountRequest.setAccountType("PERSONAL");
        createAccountRequest.setEmailAddress("testing-account@paypal.com");

        name.setFirstName("John");
        name.setLastName("Smith");
        createAccountRequest.setName(name);

        address.setLine1("1968 Ape Way");
        address.setLine2("Apt 123");
        address.setCity("Austin");
        address.setState("TX");
        address.setCountryCode("US");
        address.setPostalCode("78750"); 
        createAccountRequest.setAddress(address);

        createAccountRequest.setContactPhoneNumber("888-555-1212");
        createAccountRequest.setCurrencyCode("USD");
        createAccountRequest.setCitizenshipCountryCode("US");
        createAccountRequest.setPreferredLanguageCode("en_US");

        createAccountRequest.setRegistrationType("WEB");

        Map<String, String> paypalConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paypalConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
        paypalConfig.put("connectionTimeout", "30000");
        paypalConfig.put("requestRetries", "5");
        paypalConfig.put("IPAddress", "127.0.0.1"); 
        paypalConfig.put("account1.apiUsername", "john-facilitator_api1.gmail.com");
        paypalConfig.put("account1.apiPassword", "RQGOB80BU4XMA8");
        paypalConfig.put("account1.apiSignature", "Signature here");
        paypalConfig.put("applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");


        AdaptiveAccountsService adaptiveAccountsService = new AdaptiveAccountsService(paypalConfig);
        CreateAccountResponse createAccountResponse = adaptiveAccountsService.createAccount(createAccountRequest);
```

When I run the above code, getting the following exception.

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   com.paypal.exception.MissingCredentialException: No API accounts have
>   been configured in application properties"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: did u find any workaorund?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error but associated to the mass payment functionality. If you look into [MissingCredentialException's implementation](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paypal/exception/MissingCredentialException.java) you will see (as a comment) `MissingCredentialException is throw when the credential used are wrongly configured or not found in the application properties`

In my case, I had some properties missing (neither `clientId` nor `clientSecret`) and adding them to `sdk_config.properties` solved my problem. In case it helps, for mass payment functionality I've added:

- acct1.UserName
- acct1.Password
- acct1.Signature
- acct1.AppId
- acct1.Subject

You shold check your `sdk_config.properties` file. Hope it helps.

Comment: And idea [what my problem is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556870/missingcredentialexception-no-api-accounts-have-been-configured-in-application)?

Comment: Hi @displayname, the link is broken

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking a look - I was able to solve the issue myself and it wasn't worth keeping the question on SO :)